# Match gridlines to axis ticks in 3D regression plot (persp and rockchalk)

Tags: r, 3d, axis, scatter-plot, multiple-regression

I am trying to match my gridlines to my axis ticks in this plot so the numbers are uniform across the axis and easy to read between. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? As i am using two different packages (persp and rockchalk) at the same time i'm finding it quite difficult to find code that definitely works.

```
Sample       Coral.cover   Coral.richness   Water.Temp    fish.rich
 r.2002.c.1        59              5             23.90         57
 r.2002.c.2        71              9             33.43         70
 r.2002.c.3        55              10            23.33         55
 r.2002.c.4        58              10            22.14         56
 r.2002.c.5        62              8             26.82         61
 r.2002.c.6        65              10            29.07         64
 r.2002.s.1        86              10            38.76         84
 r.2002.s.2        71              10            30.28         68
 r.2002.s.3        91              6             27.85         89
 r.2002.s.4        63              0             28.03         62
 r.2002.s.5        75              2             31.67         75
 r.2002.s.6        63              2             29.43         63

require(Hmisc)
require(car)
require(vegan)
require(rockchalk)
require(reshape)
require(persp)

mod3 <- mcGraph3(Coral.cover, Coral.richness, fish.rich, 
             interaction = F,
             theta = -40 ,
             phi =20,
             x1lab = "",
             x2lab = "",
             ylab = "",
             x1lim = c(46,100),
             ylim = c(-2.5, 12.5),
             zlim =c(40, 100),
             r=10,
             col = 'white',
             border = 'black',
             box = T,
             axes = T,
             ticktype = "detailed",
             ntick = 4)
```

Here is what i currently have (ignoring the labels which are photoshopped):

[image: 3D Regression Plot with unaligned axis and ticks]

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

data

```
df <- structure(list(Sample = structure(1:12, .Label = c("r.2002.c.1", 
  "r.2002.c.2", "r.2002.c.3", "r.2002.c.4", "r.2002.c.5", "r.2002.c.6", 
  "r.2002.s.1", "r.2002.s.2", "r.2002.s.3", "r.2002.s.4", "r.2002.s.5", 
  "r.2002.s.6"), class = "factor"), Coral.cover = c(59L, 71L, 55L, 
  58L, 62L, 65L, 86L, 71L, 91L, 63L, 75L, 63L), Coral.richness = c(5L, 
  9L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 2L), Water.Temp = c(23.9, 
  33.43, 23.33, 22.14, 26.82, 29.07, 38.76, 30.28, 27.85, 28.03, 
  31.67, 29.43), fish.rich = c(57L, 70L, 55L, 56L, 61L, 64L, 84L, 
  68L, 89L, 62L, 75L, 63L)), .Names = c("Sample", "Coral.cover", 
  "Coral.richness", "Water.Temp", "fish.rich"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -12L))

Coral.cover <- df[,2]
Coral.richness <- df[,3]
fish.rich <- df[,5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be good idea to draw the graph without `rockchalk` package and manually add something. I used `plot3D` package (it provides extended functions of `persp`).

```
 ## preparation of some values for mesh of fitted value
fit <- lm(fish.rich ~ Coral.cover + Coral.richness)  # model
x.p <- seq(46, 100, length = 20)                     # x-grid of mesh
y.p <- seq(-2.5, 12.5, length = 20)                  # y-grid of mesh
z.p <- matrix(predict(fit, expand.grid(Coral.cover = x.p, Coral.richness = y.p)), 20) # prediction from xy-grid

library(plot3D)
  # box, grid, bottom points, and so on
scatter3D(Coral.cover, Coral.richness, rep(40, 12), colvar = NA, bty = "b2", 
          xlim = c(46,100), ylim = c(-2.5, 12.5), zlim = c(40,100), theta = -40, phi = 20, 
          r = 10, ticktype = "detailed", pch = 19, col = "gray", nticks = 4)
  # mesh, real points
scatter3D(Coral.cover, Coral.richness, fish.rich, add = T, colvar = NA, col = "blue",
          surf = list(x = x.p, y = y.p, z = z.p, facets = NA, col = "gray80"))
  # arrow from prediction to observation
arrows3D(x0 = Coral.cover, y0 = Coral.richness, z0 = fit$fitted.values, z1 = fish.rich, 
         type = "simple", lty = 2, add = T, col = "red")


 ### [bonus] persp() version
pmat <- persp(x.p, y.p, z.p, xlim = c(46,100), ylim = c(-2.5, 12.5), zlim = c(40,100), theta = -40, phi = 20, 
              r = 10, ticktype = "detailed", pch = 19, col = NA, border = "gray", nticks = 4)
for (ix in seq(50, 100, 10)) lines (trans3d(x = ix, y = c(-2.5, 12.5), z= 40, pmat = pmat), col = "black") 
for (iy in seq(0, 10, 5)) lines (trans3d(x = c(46, 100), y = iy, z= 40, pmat = pmat), col = "black")

points(trans3d(Coral.cover, Coral.richness, rep(40, 12), pmat = pmat), col = "gray", pch = 19)
points(trans3d(Coral.cover, Coral.richness, fish.rich, pmat = pmat), col = "blue")

xy0 <- trans3d(Coral.cover, Coral.richness, fit$fitted.values, pmat = pmat)
xy1 <- trans3d(Coral.cover, Coral.richness, fish.rich, pmat = pmat)
arrows(xy0[[1]], xy0[[2]], xy1[[1]], xy1[[2]], col = "red", lty = 2, length = 0.1)
```

[image]

**[response to comments]**
Your comment makes sense. But `mcGraph3()` doesn't have options related to grid and can't take `add = T` as an argument. So I showed modified `mcGraph3()` (this is a hacky way) and my function to draw grid.

Functions: `my_mcGraph3` and `persp_grid` (it might be a good idea to save this code as .R file and read by `source("file_name.R")`)

```
my_mcGraph3 <- function (x1, x2, y, interaction = FALSE, drawArrows = TRUE, 
                         x1lab, x2lab, ylab, col = "white", border = "black", x1lim = NULL, x2lim = NULL, 
                         grid = TRUE, meshcol = "black", ...)   # <-- new arguments
{
  x1range <- magRange(x1, 1.25)
  x2range <- magRange(x2, 1.25)
  yrange <- magRange(y, 1.5)
  if (missing(x1lab)) 
    x1lab <- gsub(".*\\$", "", deparse(substitute(x1)))
  if (missing(x2lab)) 
    x2lab <- gsub(".*\\$", "", deparse(substitute(x2)))
  if (missing(ylab)) 
    ylab <- gsub(".*\\$", "", deparse(substitute(y)))
  if (grid) {
    res <- perspEmpty(x1 = plotSeq(x1range, 5), x2 = plotSeq(x2range, 5),
                      y = yrange, x1lab = x1lab, x2lab = x2lab, ylab = ylab, ...)
  } else {
    if (is.null(x1lim)) x1lim <- x1range
    if (is.null(x2lim)) x2lim <- x2range
    res <- persp(x = x1range, y = x2range, z = rbind(yrange, yrange), 
                 xlab = x1lab, ylab = x2lab, zlab = ylab, xlim = x1lim, ylim = x2lim, col = "#00000000", border = NA, ...)
  }
  mypoints1 <- trans3d(x1, x2, yrange[1], pmat = res)
  points(mypoints1, pch = 16, col = gray(0.8))
  mypoints2 <- trans3d(x1, x2, y, pmat = res)
  points(mypoints2, pch = 1, col = "blue")
  if (interaction) m1 <- lm(y ~ x1 * x2) else m1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
  x1seq <- plotSeq(x1range, length.out = 20)
  x2seq <- plotSeq(x2range, length.out = 20)
  zplane <- outer(x1seq, x2seq, function(a, b) {
    predict(m1, newdata = data.frame(x1 = a, x2 = b))
  })
  for (i in 1:length(x1seq)) {
    lines(trans3d(x1seq[i], x2seq, zplane[i, ], pmat = res), lwd = 0.3, col = meshcol)
  }
  for (j in 1:length(x2seq)) {
    lines(trans3d(x1seq, x2seq[j], zplane[, j], pmat = res), lwd = 0.3, col = meshcol)
  }
  mypoints4 <- trans3d(x1, x2, fitted(m1), pmat = res)
  newy <- ifelse(fitted(m1) < y, fitted(m1) + 0.8 * (y - fitted(m1)), 
                 fitted(m1) + 0.8 * (y - fitted(m1)))
  mypoints2s <- trans3d(x1, x2, newy, pmat = res)
  if (drawArrows) 
    arrows(mypoints4$x, mypoints4$y, mypoints2s$x, mypoints2s$y, 
           col = "red", lty = 4, lwd = 0.3, length = 0.1)
  invisible(list(lm = m1, res = res))
}


persp_grid <- function(xlim, ylim, zlim, pmat, pos = c("z-", "z+", "x-", "x+", "y-", "y+"), n = 5, ...) {
  px <- pretty(xlim, n)[xlim[1] < pretty(xlim, n) & pretty(xlim, n) < xlim[2]]
  py <- pretty(ylim, n)[ylim[1] < pretty(ylim, n) & pretty(ylim, n) < ylim[2]]
  pz <- pretty(zlim, n)[zlim[1] < pretty(zlim, n) & pretty(zlim, n) < zlim[2]]
  if (any(pos == "z-" | pos == "z+")){
    zval <- ifelse(any(pos == "z-"), zlim[1], zlim[2])
    for (ix in px) lines (trans3d(x = ix, y = ylim, z = zval, pmat = pmat), ...) 
    for (iy in py) lines (trans3d(x = xlim, y = iy, z = zval, pmat = pmat), ...)
  }
  if (any(pos == "x-" | pos == "x+")){
    xval <- ifelse(any(pos == "x-"), xlim[1], xlim[2])
    for (iz in pz) lines (trans3d(x = xval, y = ylim, z = iz, pmat = pmat), ...) 
    for (iy in py) lines (trans3d(x = xval, y = iy, z = zlim, pmat = pmat), ...)
  }
  if (any(pos == "y-" | pos == "y+")){
    yval <- ifelse(any(pos == "y-"), ylim[1], ylim[2])
    for (ix in px) lines (trans3d(x = ix, y = yval, z = zlim, pmat = pmat), ...) 
    for (iz in pz) lines (trans3d(x = xlim, y = yval, z = iz, pmat = pmat), ...)
  }
}
```

Use them (if I didn't make mistakes, `my_mcGraph3(..., meshcol = "black", grid = T)` is equivalent to `mcGraph3(...)`).

```
require(rockchalk)

mod3 <- my_mcGraph3(Coral.cover, Coral.richness, fish.rich,
                 interaction = F,
                 theta = -40 ,
                 phi =20,
                 x1lab = "",
                 x2lab = "",
                 ylab = "",
                 x1lim = c(46,100),
                 x2lim = c(-2.5, 12.5),
                 zlim =c(40, 100),
                 r = 10,
                 col = 'white',
                 border = 'black',
                 box = T,
                 axes = T,
                 ticktype = "detailed",
                 ntick = 4, 
                 meshcol = "gray",    # <<- new argument
                 grid = F)            # <<- new argument

persp_grid(xlim = c(46, 100), ylim = c(-2.5, 12.5), zlim = c(40, 100), 
           pmat = mod3$res, pos = c("z-", "y+", "x+"), col = "green", lty = 2)
  # if you want only bottom grid, persp_grid(..., pos = "z-", ...)

# note
magRange(fish.rich, 1.5)   # c(38, 106) is larger than zlim, so warning message comes.
```

functions of `persp` draw a graph using `base` plot, in other words, first they translate 3d-coordinate into 2d-coordinate and give it to functions of `base` plot. You can get 2d-coordinate from 3d-coordinate by `trans3d(3d_coodinates, pmat)`. Say, you want to draw line from `x=46, y=-2.5, z=100` to `x=46, y=12.5, z=100`. you can get `pmat` by `pmat <- persp(...)` or `mod <- mcGraph3(...); pmat <- mod$res`. (please use below code after above code runs)

```
coords_2d_0 <- trans3d(46, -2.5, 100, pmat = mod3$res)  # 2d_coordinates of the start point
coords_2d_1 <- trans3d(46, 12.5, 100, pmat = mod3$res)  # 2d_coordinates of the end point
points(coords_2d_0, col = 2, pch = 19); points(coords_2d_1, col = 2, pch = 19)

xx <- c(coords_2d_0$x, coords_2d_1$x)
yy <- c(coords_2d_0$y, coords_2d_1$y)
lines(xx, yy, col = "blue", lwd = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot that is exactly what i was looking for. Although i do have one question. The reason i went for rockchalk was just because i found the code i used very simple whereas i would have personally struggled to write anywhere near what you just produced. In this sense, how could i add back dotted lines to fill out the cube like i previously had? It's mainly so you can the exact point where the regression plane touches the front of the box.

Comment: You can disregard that comment, i just ran the code and it is there. Thanks for your help.